# How to authenticate with a backend server?

Tags: java, jquery, grails, backend, google-authentication

Does anyone can help me to get a solution for authenticate with a backend server ? I am logging in in my platform with a google account and I post the `id_token` (using ajax).

```js
var msg = $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "controller/action", data: token, async: false}).responseText;
if (msg=="ok"){
    window.location = "controller/action";
}
else {
    window.location = "controller/action";
}
```

Now, I want to authenticate the token in order to save user information (name, image,email) in database.
I see this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth. Is there a way to use it?

Comment: You backend is in java?

Comment: it is a grails controller

Comment: Check this link it is a good sample project https://github.com/bagage/grails-google-authentification-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send get Request in any RestClient and replace xyz with your token:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=xyz
```

Once you get Response in restclient then simply assemble this get request in your convenient language. Get request in grails [see this](http://www.leveluplunch.com/groovy/examples/make-get-request-httpbuilder-apache-httpcomponents/)

hope it helps you

Comment: The result of https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=xyz is json so I can take the info I want. But can you explain me, how I will post this and how I will handle it on server? Is there a sample code?